# Rule based styling with select-by-intersection syntax

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, rule-based

I want to do rule based styling for a selection of gridded polygons dependent on their position relating to another layer. I want to show the polygon that a point feature based in an atlas falls within which I have managed with

```
intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry)
```

The tougher bit is that I also want to show the 8 grid boxes that surround the central grid box in another style. Unfortunately, as the grid is rectangular, not square, I cannot just use a buffer of the atlas feature as when the feature is close to the edge it will show features to the east/west before north/south. I have tried using nested intersections such as

```
intersects($geometry,intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry))
```

but no luck so far. I want to do this dynamically so it shows just the grid surrounding the atlas feature and without having to create any more new layers.

## [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your objection to buffering only applies to the point.  It would not be a problem if you buffer the polygon that you have just found.  Also, instead on doing a buffer operation followed by and intersects, why not search in a single step with "touches" based on the red rectangle?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, the red rectangle is not a separate shapefile, it just styled based on the rule 

intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry)

I've tried using 

touches($geometry,intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry))

in the hope that it will select all the boxes that touch the intersected box but it doesn't seem to be working as I would hope.